# how to get not null values while querying mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query which will fetch the equipment records as well as its associated data from the association table. My query is like:

```
select e.Name,ec.Name as EquipmentClassName, s.Name as SiteName
from  equipment e
left join site s on (e.SiteID = s.ID or e.SiteID is NULL and s.ID is NULL)
left join equipmentclass ec on e.EquipmentClassID=ec.ID
where e.id like '%' and (
  (isNull(e.Name) OR e.Name=  CASE  WHEN COALESCE('','') = '' THEN e.Name   ELSE ''  END)
 and (isNull(e.EquipmentClassID) OR e.EquipmentClassID=  CASE  WHEN COALESCE('1','') = '' THEN e.EquipmentClassID   ELSE ''  END)
 and (isNull(e.SiteID) OR e.SiteID=  CASE  WHEN COALESCE('','') = '' THEN e.SiteID   ELSE ''  END)
)
```

ok when i don't pass any parameter in the where clause, i get all the records including null records as well.
But when i pass any of the parameter i get all the records again. What i am expecting here is a filtered data.

Suppose i have two records as
Equip1, class1,null and Equi2, null,Site2

Now in the where clause i am passing Class1, so i should get a single record which contains class1 instead of two records.

How can i do this?

Comment: Please update the tags.  SQL Server and MySQL often require different solutions, for the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for tag problem. Didn't pay attention to what tags i am selecting.. My Mistake

Comment: Can you provide sample records and the output you would expect that sample to produce?  SO has a [handy guide to providing sample data](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which you may find useful.  I didn't downvote this question, so I can't be sure why it has a score of -1.  But if I had to guess I would say you've lost points because your question is hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for the reply handy.. I have updated my question to make it more simpler. And here is my sample records: Equip1, class1,null and Equi2, null,Site2. When i pass Class1 in the where clause i want to get the first record.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE equipmentData
@Name                   varchar(90) = null, 
@EquipmentClassID       varchar(90) = null,
@LocationID             varchar(90) = null,
@ParentEquipmentID      varchar(90) = null,
@EquipmentLevelID       varchar(90) = null,
@SiteID                 varchar(90) = null

AS
BEGIN

select e.ID,
e.Name,
ec.Name as EquipmentClassName,
 loc.Name as LocationName,
  pe.Name as ParentEquipmentName ,
  eql.Name as EquipmentLevelName, 
  s.Name as SiteName,
  ep.ID as EquipmentPropertyID,
  ep.Name as EquipmentPropertyName,
  ep.Description as EquipmentPropertyDesc, 
  ep.Mandatory,
  ep.SeqNbr,
  ep.DataType,
  ep.RuleIDs,
  ep.DefaultValue,
  ep.UOM,
  epv.Value
from  equipment e
inner join equipmentclass ec            on   e.EquipmentClassID=ec.ID
left join site s                        on   (e.SiteID = s.ID or e.SiteID is NULL and s.ID is NULL)
left join location loc                  on   e.LocationID=loc.ID
left join equipment pe                  on   pe.ID=e.ParentEquipmentID
left join equipmentlevel eql            on   eql.ID = e.EquipmentLevelID
left join extendedproperty ep           on   ep.ObjectTypeID = e.ObjectTypeID 
left join extendedpropertyvalue epv     on   epv.InstanceID = e.ID
where 
e.id like '%' 
AND (e.Name             = @Name                 or isnull(e.Name,'')= '')
AND (@EquipmentClassID  = @EquipmentClassID     or isnull(e.EquipmentClassID,'')= '')
AND (@LocationID        = @LocationID           or isnull(e.LocationID,'')= '')
AND (@ParentEquipmentID = @ParentEquipmentID    or isnull(e.ParentEquipmentID,'')= '')
AND (@EquipmentLevelID  = @EquipmentLevelID     or isnull(e.EquipmentLevelID,'')= '')
AND (@SiteID            = @SiteID               or isnull(e.SiteID,'')= '')

END

EXEC equipmentData @Name='',@EquipmentClassID='',
 @LocationID='',@ParentEquipmentID='',@EquipmentLevelID='',@SiteID=''
```

First copy the above code except the last line i.e.

```
EXEC equipmentData @Name='',@EquipmentClassID='',
     @LocationID='',@ParentEquipmentID='',@EquipmentLevelID='',@SiteID=''
```

AND press F5 then run the last line code by passing parameter in singlequotes as per your need..you will get your data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply pankaj. Sorry for my lack of knowledge but i am wondering how can i pass EquipmentClassID in the where clause?

Comment: ok i got it your query.... either you can make stored procedure if have good knowledge of T-Sql or simply declare variable im sending you updated code ok

Comment: Thanks for the help pankaj.. But i am getting error while running the stored procedure code as You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@Name                   varchar(90) = null, 
@EquipmentClassID       varchar(90' at line 2

Comment: this code is for sql server :)

Comment: :(. Well i am working on mysql

Comment: don't worry roy... stored procedure are almost same in mysql and sql server... few syntax  are different and rest will be same.. vist some site for syntax and then update my code and use it :)

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx use this link :)